# Remove header and footer when I click print button using Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-3

Footer:

```
<script>  
 $('#print').click(function(){
      var printElm = $('.print-this');
      if(printElm.length == 0) {
        alert("Nothing to print!"); return;
      }
      printElm.printThis({
        header:'<h3 style="text-align:center;">Printing Elements<h3>'
      });
    });
</script>
```

View:

```
<div class="container print-this">
 <table class="table table-hover" style="border:3px solid 
   black;font-family:Roboto;font-size:15px">
     <tr style="border-bottom:hidden">
        <td colspan="5" style="font-weight:bold">School_name</td>
        <td align="right" style="font-weight:bold">Roll NO</td>
      </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Normally print button is display in footer when I click that button it execute the print function in footer in that situation I need to hide the header and footer in print page.How can I do this??Can You please help me to complete the task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Footer:

```
<style>
  @media print {
  #header, #footer { display: none; }
}
</style>
```

Just assign the id for header and footer and put the above code in footer and when you click print button, it hides the header and footer of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, I do it using jquery, I put the part that I need to print into a separate div.

Here is an example of how you could do it yourself.

Hope it serves you well!

```js
$('BUTTON TO PRINT').on('click', function(){
$(this).text('').append('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa fa-fw margin-bottom"></i>');
var WinPrint = window.open('', '', 'left=0,top=0, toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');
WinPrint.document.write($('DIV YOU WANT TO PRINT').html());
WinPrint.document.close();
WinPrint.focus();
WinPrint.print();
WinPrint.close();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
  @media print {
   @page {
                                    margin-top: 0;
                                    margin-bottom: 0;
                                    }
                                    body  {
                                    padding-top: 5px;
                                    padding-bottom: 5px ;
                                    }
}
```